# How to get the right timezone in central europe?

Tags: python

I am living in the Netherlands, in which CET and CEST are used.
Running JavaScript I indeed get these time zones on my laptop.

However using Python (2.7, 3.6, 3.7) I get WET and WEST.
This isn't correct, as in countries in these zones (e.g. Great Brittain) the clock indicates one hour earlier (which is quite logical, the earth turning eastward).

Why this deviation and how can I correct it?

[EDIT]

```
import time
print (time.tzname)
```

Result:

```
('W. Europe Standard Time', 'W. Europe Daylight Time')
```

I'd expect:

```
('Central European Standard Time', 'Central European Daylight Time')
```

I am not using pytz or any lib that doesn't come with the distribution.

Comment: *"I get WET and WEST"* – You get that when you do what?

Comment: How exactly are you getting times in python? Are you using `pytz`?

Comment: See below \[EDIT\]

Comment: So both Python and Javascript are running on the same machine, but are giving you different "local" timezones? The browser will use system settings unless explicitly overridden, but Python can be run any number of different ways and it may get its information from other sources and/or you can override it in a number of ways. How exactly are you running your Python?

Comment: I am running Python in a Windows Powershell command prompt under Windows 10 set in the english language. Could it be Python looks to the GUI language settings? If so, how can I override that. I don't want my computer to   talk dutch to me, as dutch computer terminology is highly non-standard... And yes, JS and Python run on the same machine under the same OS with the same system settings.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your environment variables. E.g. on my Debian Linux:

```
$ python3 -c "import time; print (time.tzname)"
('CET', 'CEST')
```

but:

```
$ TZ=WET python3 -c "import time; print (time.tzname)"
('WET', 'WEST')
```

Comment: I've tried setting the TZ environment var under windows in several ways. But it doesn't work properly. If I set the timezone to Amsterdam, it erroneously calls it W. European Standard Time. If I set it explicitly to W. Europan standard time it only picks up the first three chars. If I use the TZUTIL utility, it displays "daylight time" instead of "summer time", which I can't change. If I use powershell: same problem. Some aspects of Windows are, well, confusing, to say it nicely...